# Prevent moving on Google Maps with keyboard keys

Tags: javascript, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-api-3

I want to prevent a Google map to move when the keys <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd> are pressed:

```js
var map;
var element = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
function initMaps() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
    zoom: 17,
    center: { lat: parseFloat(48), lng: parseFloat(2) }
  });
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(48,2);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos, map: map, title: '', draggable: true });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: '<div contenteditable="true" id="infowindowtext">Test</div>' });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document, 'keydown', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 34) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert();
        return false;
    }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map-container">
<div id="map-canvas" style="min-height: 400px;"></div>  
</div><script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIjN23OujC_NdFfvX4_AuoGBbkx7aHMf0&callback=initMaps"></script>
```

But this is what happens:

1. Click on the map (to give focus) and press <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>
2. The map doesn't move
3. The `alert()` popup appears
4. Let's click OK
5. **The map moves** (unwanted)

Another example :

1. Click on the marker editable textbox and write some text
2. Press <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>
3. **The map moves** (unwanted) but the cursor doesn't move in the textbox

**How to totally prevent the map from moving when doing <kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!

We use jquery to get the active element so we can watch the keyDown.

Then check to see if the code of the button is 34, if so we return false.

use some jQuery:

```
<script>
  $($(document.activeElement)).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code === 34) {
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**: since updated question leave above as is and change js to:
set JS to:

```
    itens = [{
  lat: -22.9187655,
  lng: -43.258619
}, {
  lat: -23.5245363,
  lng: -51.6667318
}];
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 5,
  minZoom: 4,
  maxZoom: 20,
  center: {
    lat: 48,
    lng: 2
  },
  fullscreenControl: true
}

var map;

function initMaps() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(48, 2);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    title: '',
    draggable: true
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    map.setOptions({
      keyboardShortcuts: false
    });
  });

}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: '<div contenteditable="true" id="infowindowtext">Test</div>',
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
  map.setOptions({
    keyboardShortcuts: true
  });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE (UPDATED)** : https://jsfiddle.net/cmjcs5eL/10/

Comment: Thanks. I slightly updated the question to reflect the real full problem. When you launch the snippet, you have a marker, and an editable textbox. If you click on the textbox and then RIGHT ARROW, it moves the map... If you filter keyCode 39 with your technique @John, then the map won't move (good), but the cursor won't move in the textbox (bad). Do you see the problem? Any idea?

Comment: see changes, believe it achieves what you need